# CGRectContainsPoint checking a view within a subview?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to check for a collision of an `UIView` that is in the main view, with a `UILabel` that is a subview of another view in the main view.

When I use `CGRectContainsPoint`, it does not return true. When I check the `UILabel's` frame, it returns values relative to the subview it's in, not it's absolute position. I figured this might be the problem.

If so, how do I specify that I want `UILabel's` absolute values for the frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert coordinates between different coordinate systems using the `NSView` methods:

```
- convertRect:(NSRect) fromView:(NSView)
- convertRect:(NSRect) toView:(NSView)
```

If the second argument is `nil`, the coordinates are converted from/to window base coordinates. Similar methods exist for `NSPoint` and `NSSize` variables. One solution would be to convert all rectangles and points to window base coordinates and check for collision in those coordinates.